# Resistance and current of IO pins

Tags: current, pcb-design

I am using a STM32F103C8T6 MCU to control a [DRV8825 chip](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slvsa73f/slvsa73f.pdf?ts=1711070175140) and it just occurred to me that I never considered how much current goes from the pin of the MCU to the pin of whatever chip I am using. For instance, if there is a MCU GPIO connected to a nENBL pin of the DRV8825, how will I know how much current will pass through if I set the GPIO to output high? In other words, how will I know the resistance of the pins and when do I need a resistor in between? How is setting a GPIO to output high different form a pullup resistor?

Comment: To limit the current flowing from the GPIO pin to the DRV8825 pin, you can use a series resistor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *how will I know how much current will pass through if I set the GPIO
> to output high?*

It tells you in the data sheet you linked for the DRV8825. It's on page 6. It tells you that logic input pins take 100 μA when the logic voltage driving it is 3.3 volts. This includes the current of the internal pull-down resistor (100 kΩ) inside the DRV8825.

> *when do I need a resistor in between?*

There is no reason to use one; the loading of the DRV8825 input is low and won't cause your MCU's IO pin any problems.

> *How is setting a GPIO to output high different form a pullup resistor?*

Vastly different. The GPIO pin can actively pull its output high and, actively pull its output low. It uses a push-pull output configuration. A pull-up resistor (usually) weakly pulls up an input pin using a moderate to small current and, in the case of the DRV8825 input it has to have a resistance somewhat less than 100 kΩ to do so.

Answer (score 0):

> how will I know how much current will pass through if I set the GPIO to output high?

As in Andy Aka's answer, this is in the datasheet.  It **should** always in the datasheet, and it **is** almost always in the datasheet.

For normal CMOS logic, from the perspective of an output pin, input pins look like capacitors to ground.  When the logic level changes there's a small spike of current, then things settle down to a level of current that's usually negligible.

> In other words, how will I know the resistance of the pins

For normal CMOS logic, modeling the pins as resistors probably isn't a good idea -- on the input side, any resistive effect is swamped by the capacitance at switching; on the output side, by the time you see the pin acting like a resistor you're pulling way more current from it than you should.

You're better off looking at the data sheet.  If the datasheet is reasonably complete it'll tell you the input currents at high and low logic levels, and the output voltage at zero current and the extremes of the recommended output current ranges.

Note that logic chips, microcontrollers, memory chips and the like tend to be very well specified in this area, while specialty chips like sensors can be lacking.  Usually when that happens it's best to treat them like logic that has high capacitance (on input) and low drive levels (on output) -- and perhaps build a test board and find out their limitations yourself.

> and when do I need a resistor in between?

Almost never.

You may need them if it's very fast I/O, to impedance match an output to a circuit board trace -- this is more rare today than it was 20 years ago, because manufacturers know how to build that into chips these days.  If you're not dealing with switching speeds in the hundreds of MHz, or launching signals across feet of cable (or backplane), then you don't need to worry.

You may need them to do level switching -- i.e., if you're driving a 5V output to a 3.3V part that isn't 5V tolerant, or some other, similar, unhappy voltage combination.  Then you'd need to have a resistive divider (or, with certain older "5V tolerant" parts) a series resistor.